# How can I sort the a list of getScanResults() based on Signal strength in ascending order?

Tags: android, sorting, wifi, signals

I am storing scanresult into list as per the code below:

```
List<ScanResult> results = wifi.getScanResults();
             sb = new StringBuilder();
            try
            {
                for(int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++){
                    sb.append(new Integer(i+1).toString() + ".");
                    sb.append("SSID:-").append((results.get(i).SSID).toString());
                    sb.append("BSSID:-").append((results.get(i).BSSID).toString());
                    sb.append("Level:-").append((results.get(i).level));
                    sb.append("Frequency:-").append((results.get(i).frequency));
                    sb.append("\n\n");
                }
                textStatus.setText("");
                textStatus.append("\n\n\n");
                textStatus.append(sb);
            }
```

I want to sort this result based on signal strength (level) so I am creating a 2D array that have the data level and Mac. so I have written code for this:

```
String rssi[][]=new String[2][results.size()];
for(int i = 0; i <results.size(); i++){
         rssi[0][i] = String.valueOf(results.get(i).level);
         rssi[1][i]= results.get(i).BSSID;
}

StringBuilder tmp=new StringBuilder();
Arrays.sort(rssi,new Comparator<String[]>() {
       @Override
       public int compare(String[] str1, String[] str2) {
           final String lv1= str1[0];
           final String lv2= str2[0];
           return lv1.compareTo(lv2);
       }
);
```

Based on above code I am expecting `rssi[][]` in sorted order, but it is not happening...

Answer (score 9):

Try this

```
     Comparator<ScanResult> comparator = new Comparator<ScanResult>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(ScanResult lhs, ScanResult rhs) {
            return (lhs.level <rhs.level ? -1 : (lhs.level==rhs.level ? 0 : 1));
        }
     }
     List<ScanResult> results = wifi.getScanResults();
     Collections.sort(results, comparator);

     //Here your list is sorted by level
```

Comment: You can also take advantage of the comparator built into the `WifiManager.compareSignalLevel` method in place of the statement on the `return` line: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#compareSignalLevel(int, int)